# can we have a foreign key which is not a primary key in any other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys

it is written in every book that foreign keys are actually primary key in some other table but can we have a foreign key which is not primary key in any other table

Comment: there is no specific reason somebody asked me this and i got confused thats why i just wanted to know that's it

Comment: Why? Well that depends on what your reasons are for choosing a primary key in the first place - formally speaking there is no absolute reason for choosing one primary key over another so there are no particular grounds for saying why it would or wouldn't be the same one used for foreign key references. Also, it's potentially desirable in some cases to use more than one candidate key per table as a foreign key reference. In that case, one of those references obviously isn't the primary key - unless you want to call more than one key the "primary" one!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes - you can have a foreign key that references a unique index in another table.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX01_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable(SomeUniqueColumn)

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourChildTable
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ChildTable_Table
   FOREIGN KEY(YourFKColumn) REFERENCES dbo.YourTable(SomeUniqueColumn)
```

Comment: This is correct in Microsoft SQL Server but it isn't stanard SQL and isn't supported by all other DBMSs. In ISO standard SQL there is no such thing as an index and FOREIGN KEY constraints are always required to match UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraints. Personally I'd always prefer to use unique constraints rather than unique indexes without a constraint. I think a constraint makes the intended meaning clearer and the constraint syntax is more likely to be understood by another database developer.

Answer (score 14):

By definition a foreign key must reference a candidate key of some table. It doesn't necessarily have to be the primary key.

As a matter of detail the constraint called a FOREIGN KEY in SQL isn't exactly equivalent to the textbook definition of a foreign key in the relational model. SQL's FOREIGN KEY constraint differs because:

- it can reference any set of columns subject to a uniqueness constraint even if they are not candidate keys (superkeys or nullable columns for example).
- it may include nulls, in which case the constraint is not enforced
- its syntax depends on column order, so a fk constraint on (A,B) referencing (A,B) is different to a constraint on (B,A) referencing (A,B).

Comment: APC not sure why you want to edit this to replace "SQL" with "SQL Server". My comments apply to SQL (meaning the standard language defined by ISO). They apply to all implementations of SQL that I'm familiar with - not just SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah, what is it with these people who edit posts without knowing what they are doing.  I vote for disallowing edits to Answers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes , There can be a foreign key which is unique key in other table as Unique key is subset of primary key but not the exact primary key.

So that's possible that foreign key is unique key in aother table.

Answer (score 1):

General standard answer is no.  It is only possible if foreign key refers any column uniquely in other table. That means foreign key must be the candidate key in other table and primary key is also a candidate key the table.