# MySQL error cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

what is wrong?

```
mysql> create table price(
    -> p_code char(1) not null,
    -> p_description varchar(20),
    -> p_rentfee decimal(2,2) not null,
    -> p_dylatefee decimal(2,2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

mysql> create table movie(
    -> mv_no char(4) not null,
    -> mv_name varchar(50) not null,
    -> mv_year char(4) not null,
    -> mv_cost decimal(2,2) not null,
    -> mv_genre varchar(15) not null,
    -> p_code char(1) not null,
    -> foreign key (p_code) references price(p_code));
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

mysql>
```

Comment: is `p_code` a primary key in your `price` table?

Comment: This is just a guess, but shouldn't `price.p_code` and `movie.p_code` be indexes in their own tables?

Answer (score 7):

`price.p_code` is not the primary key for `price`. Try:

```
create table price(
p_code char(1) not null PRIMARY KEY,
p_description varchar(20),
p_rentfee decimal(2,2) not null,
p_dylatefee decimal(2,2));
```

In general, foreign keys must reference a primary/unique key, a whole primary/unique key, and nothing but a primary/unique key.

In some RDBMS, for example SQL Server, you *can* reference a column with a unique *index* (not key) (see [can we have a foreign key which is not a primary key in any other table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895219/can-we-have-a-foreign-key-which-is-not-a-primary-key-in-any-other-table)), but this is non-standard behavior.

Answer (score 7):

- **Engine** should be the same *e.g. InnoDB*
- **Datatype** should be the same, and with same length. *e.g. VARCHAR(20)*
- **Collation** Columns charset should be the same. *e.g. utf8*
  *Watchout: Even if your tables have same Collation, columns still could have different one.*
- **Unique** - Foreign key should refer to field that is unique (usually primary key) in the referenced table.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful details. Had the same issues. I'd created one table with `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin` and the referenced table was created with `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4` only. Using the same collation and everything works as expected. :)

Answer (score 2):

`p_code` should be a primary key in your `price` table:

```
create table price(
-> p_code char(1) not null,
-> p_description varchar(20),
-> p_rentfee decimal(2,2) not null,
-> p_dylatefee decimal(2,2),
-> PRIMARY KEY ( p_code ));
```

Answer (score 0):

set **p_code** to be a key ,either set it to be a **unique key** or **primary key**.

Answer (score 0):

1. The referenced column `price.p_code` must be unique (primary or unique key need to be created).
2. Both tables must be **InnoDb** tables, use `ENGINE = INNODB` in `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The data type for the child column must match the parent column exactly. For example, since price.p_code is an char(1), movie.p_code also needs to be an char(1) and price.p_code need be a Primary Key or need create a Index.