# MySQL Error Code 1215: Cannot add foreign key Constraint on ALTER TABLE : Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join, normalization

I want to add foreign key Constraint on my existing tables(type InnoDB) 
,I have two tables listed below:

```
tbl_users : [ user_id(INT,AUTO_INCREMENT), user_name,--- etc]
tbl_users_meta : [ user_meta_id(INT,AUTO_INCREMENT), user_id(INT),--- etc]
```

I have already created index '**user_id**' on '**tbl_users_meta**' listed below :

[image]

Here is my Query but i am getting (MySQL Error Code 1215: ) each time.what is the problem i can getting it ?

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_users_meta` 
ADD  CONSTRAINT `fk users user_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES 
`sanskrut`.`tbl_users`(`user_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: both tables are in same db?

Comment: yes both are in same db

Comment: check mysql error logs and share details...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error cannot add foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842111/mysql-error-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: i am  working at localhost WAMP server, where i can find MySQL error log ?

Comment: ["MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys *and referenced keys* so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) I don't see an index on `tbl_users.user_id`. You have one on `tbl_users_meta`, but I don't think that's actually necessary in this case, as MySQL would create an index on the *foreign* table, if required, automatically. Typically you'd mark `tbl_users.user_id` as `PRIMARY KEY` for `tbl_users`.

Comment: yes it is, 'user_id' is a PRIMARY KEY for 'tbl_users' and user_meta_id is a PRIMARY KEY for 'tbl_users_meta'. and another index is 'user_id' in 'tbl_users_meta' as you can see in image attached in my question. then what is the problem. can you explain more ?

Comment: @amitgupta  ADD  CONSTRAINT `fk users user_id` --  are there spaces in between ?

Answer (score 0):

TRY with the same query you have writen with a small modification:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `tbl_users_meta` 
ADD  CONSTRAINT `fk users user_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES 
`sanskrut`.`tbl_users`(`user_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Hope it'll work

Comment: getting same error  using this -  #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: have you tried specifying `database_name` preceding both the table names?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with what you've written, so there must be something you haven't posted affecting the problem. For example, on MySQL version 5.5.44, I can successfully execute the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE sanskrut;
USE sanskrut;
CREATE TABLE tbl_users (user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, user_name VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE tbl_users_meta (user_meta_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, user_id INT);
CREATE INDEX user_id ON tbl_users_meta (user_id);
ALTER TABLE `tbl_users_meta` 
ADD  CONSTRAINT `fk users user_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES 
`sanskrut`.`tbl_users`(`user_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

...which finishes with your exact problem statement, copied and pasted, and works just fine.

I'd suspect, as I mentioned in the comments, that there's an index missing or possibly a datatype mismatch. You may find it helpful to add the output of:

```
DESC tbl_users;
DESC tbl_users_meta;
SHOW indexes FROM tbl_users;
SHOW indexes FROM tbl_users_meta;
```

...to your question.