# multiple foreign keys cannot be added

Tags: mysql

I am wondering why i cannot be able to add this foreign keys.This is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE members(
  member_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  num_1 int,
  num_2 int,
  password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (member_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE contacts(
  contact_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  s1 int,
  phone_number VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  s2 int,
  s3 int,
  PRIMARY KEY (contact_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (s1) REFERENCES members(num_1) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (s2) REFERENCES members(num_2) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (s3) REFERENCES members(member_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I get this error on the mysql terminal 
`ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Is there a problem with my schema?.

Comment: you may not having index on `num_1` and `num_2`. that may be the reason

Comment: Usually foreign key needs a primary key in the referencing table

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I think Unique key

Comment: Unique key will work too

Comment: **Note:** In some RDBMS, for example SQL Server, you can reference a column with a unique index (not key) (see [can we have a foreign key which is not a primary key in any other table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895219/can-we-have-a-foreign-key-which-is-not-a-primary-key-in-any-other-table)), but this is non-standard behavior.

Comment: wow, because num_1 and num_2 are not unique :D, FK should point to a key that is unique and not null, how do you point to num_1, it doesn't make sense, what are you trying to reach exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me this way:

```
CREATE TABLE members(
  member_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  num_1 int,
  num_2 int,
  password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (member_id),
  key idx_num1 (num_1),
  key idx_num2 (num_2)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE contacts(
  contact_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  s1 int,
  phone_number VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  s2 int,
  s3 int,
  PRIMARY KEY (contact_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (s1) REFERENCES members(num_1) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (s2) REFERENCES members(num_2) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (s3) REFERENCES members(member_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Just added

```
  key idx_num1 (num_1),
  key idx_num2 (num_2)
```

in table members. Foreign keys need to reference an indexed column (not necessarily unique and not necessarily `NOT NULL`able).

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.