# Entity Framework Key Name on Parent Entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have classes that look like this:

```
public class Signer
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]       
    public Guid EntityUUID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid SignerUUID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityUUID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]       
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? EntityUUID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Signer> Signers { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to create the migration for this, EF is trying to make the User.Id column the parent of the relationship with Signer, which fails because they are of different types.  What I need to happen is have User.EntityUUID be the parent for the relationship, but I can't find anything that allows me to set the parent side of the relationship.  I looked at InverseProperty attribute, but that doesn't seems to help my situation.  Annotations would be my preferred fix.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
A co-worker claims this isn't possible currently with EF, anyone able to confirm?

Comment: That's no issue with EF, that's just not how foreign keys work. Because a foreign key has to uniquely identify a row in another table, it has to reference the primary key of this table, which is `Id` in your case.

Comment: The diagram could help to understand what you exactly need. For complicated relationships is better to use Fluent API than Data Annotations.

Comment: @FlorianHaider, not true (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895219/can-we-have-a-foreign-key-which-is-not-a-primary-key-in-any-other-table).  Any key on the parent table is eligible.

Comment: @MiroslavHolec, as of EF 6, pretty much everything in fluent API is in annotations.  But anyway, do you have a fluent API solution to this?

Comment: @DanJ ok, I did not know about that. It seems this can be done on MS SQL Server. Anyway it is not implemented in EF yet. They are working on this for EF 7 though https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support

Answer (score 0):

Found this, looks like it is coming in EF 7 but not currently available.
[Alternate Keys in Entity Framework](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/Alternate-Keys-in-Entity-Framework-7?WT.mc_id=dlvr_twitter_ch9)