# How to make a no primary key with datatype sting as foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to make a non primary key as foreign key in another table whose datatype is string.I'm trying to reference doctor_id from users table

**Referenced Table**

[image]

**Referencing Table**

[image]

Comment: foreign key must have same type as parent table primary id

Comment: doctor_id in both table are with same type you see

Comment: ah i see, maybe you try to do relation on model level without define foreign key on db shema?

Comment: May you make it a little bit clear kindly? I didn't get you

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
`laravue_server`.`#sql-1430_94` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL:
 alter table `doctor_schedules` add constraint `doctor_schedules_doctor_id_foreign` foreign key (
`doctor_id`) references `users` (`doctor_id`))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895219/can-we-have-a-foreign-key-which-is-not-a-primary-key-in-any-other-table have you read this?

Comment: I read it before. and I formed foreign key accordingly. But now my project purpose the I need to add foreign key referencing a non primary key or any kind of key in users table

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `unique` modifier on your column.

```
$table->string('doctor_id')->unique();
```

however, if you set `nullable` as the modifier like:

```
$table->string('doctor_id')->unique()->nullable();
```

it will present another problem when it has multiple records with the same value of  `null`.